# Custom Options Menu item does not trigger `onOptionsItemSelected` when clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appbarlayout

In my top AppBar options menu I needed an custom menu item, so I defined it like so in my Fragment:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, R.string.share)
            .setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_share_button)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.settings)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.bootstrap_icon_gear_fill)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            0 -> reportDownload()
            1 -> navigateToEditReport()
            else -> return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

`R.layout.menu_item_share_button` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/share"
    android:letterSpacing="0"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:tooltipText="@string/share"
    android:textColor="@color/caredx_uikit_active_button"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

My problem is that the `onCreateOptionsMenu` is not getting called for the fist menu item with the custom view set by `setActionView`. It works fine for the second menu item.

What should I do to make it work? I thought that click events are getting created automatically for menu items.

I was following this tutorial: https://stablekernel.com/article/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/
(Except for creating menu items as xml file. I created them programatically.)

Comment: from layout?  .setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_share_button)

Comment: @GobuCSG I did that and it does not work. The click handler is not present